# Empty Usage Analysis Logs

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-analytics

I am running SharePoint Foundation in a two server farm. I set the farm up about a year ago and was only recently asked to enable site analytics for a particular web application. The 'Usage and Health data collection' service application was created when I initially set up the farm. When I click on the 'Manage' button for it, I can see the log files should be stored in the default location (../14/LOGS). When I look at this folder on either server, there are ~5400 log files there, but they are all 0kb in size. If you open any of them, they are empty.

Last week I deleted this service application and recreated it, but the problem still persists. In the web application, when you go to Site Settings - 'Site Web Analytics Reports', the following message is displayed:

> A web analytics report is not available for this site. Usage
>   processing may be disabled on this server or the usage data for this
>   site has not been processed yet.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that the service application is not properly created via user interface. Try using this to properly create it http://sharepointreporter.wordpress.com/2010/12/08/sharepoint-2010-usage-and-health-data-collection-service-application/

Once you validate they are started, you need to configure it as detailed here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/shyjumohan/configure-web-analytics-and-health-data-collection-in-sharepoint-2010/

Only after all this is done, try again after the Job executes at least once

Comment: Thanks, after following the instructions in the links above the Service Application was configured correctly, but the Log files were still 0kb. I also noticed I was receiving no messages from ULS, followed bobgreen84's instructions at: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointadminprevious/thread/bd67d5ee-7d44-46c6-b768-cccebb7220e9/ and this resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the underlying IIS access logs and run them through a separate web analytics tool.  There are a number of self-hosted solutions out there.